# Adobe InDesign: how can I get the CMYK code from a color that I have saved in RGB in the swatches?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cmyk, rgb

I'm making a work for school and I have to put together color palettes for some pictures. I also want to indicate the RGB and the CMYK code but when I get a color from a picture with the Eyedropper Tool I only get the RGB. I assume it is so because the picture is in RGB mode.

How can I get in a fast way the correspondent CMYK code for that specific color? (In fact I see default colors in the swatches above mine that are in CMYK...maybe there's a way to switch easily from RGB to CMYK inside the swatches..)

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41544324/stack%20exchange.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the swatch on your swatch panel. Go to Swatch Options. Change the Color Mode to CMYK. You will get decimal points which isn't a problem really but if it annoys you just then decide to round up or round down.

[image: Swatch Screenshot]